# tmux from cron fails "lost server"

Tags: cron, tmux

I have a bash script which kills and recreates a tmux session, which works fine run from command line, but when I run from cron the tmux kill works but the create session outputs "lost server" and doesn't create any session.

The cron configuration is done with `crontab -e` run from the same user as successfully runs the script from command line. I'm not aware of anything in the user environment (no personalised profile stuff). This is running on Ubuntu 18.4

The tmux script is:

```
tmux kill-session -t "bothapps"
tmux new-session -s "bothapps" \; \
send-keys "htop" C-m \; \
split-window -v -p 65\; \
send-keys "sudo python3 myapp1.py" C-m \; \
split-window -h \; \
send-keys "sudo python3 myapp2.py" C-m \; \
detach
```

The `kill-session` works but `new-session` outputs "lost server" without creating a session. I guess it's something to do with the cron shell not having an attached tty but don't know how to resolve it.

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you, instead of `send-keys`, use the fact that `new-session` and `split-window` takes a shell command as argument? E.g., `tmux new -s name htop \; split -v -65 sudo python3 myapp.py \; split -h sudo python3 myapp2.py \; detach`

Comment: Oh nice trick! I'll try that - do you think the 'send' might be the issue, with cron confusing where it should send?

Comment: I don't know if that's the issue (did it work?). If it is, it could have to do with interactivity (something to do with not having a TTY, as you say). But I'm handwaving here and haven't tested anything.

Comment: Unfortunately I got exactly the same response "lost server" from the alternative way of using tmux without `send-keys` (although it is a neater way to do it)

Comment: FYI I tried not using cron but have one of the tmux windows run a process that polls around sleeping for the same time as the cron did and then running the same tmux script as above, result is similar in that the tmux kill works but not the other bits - I thought that was because I'm running tmux inside tmux but I tried running with 'nohup' and/or using `&` to run the tmux script in background but with the same effect... not sure if that fails for the same or different reasons to the cron approach